# SQL get the min/max time per date in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, max, min

i need a help here, im trying to build a query which returns the max and min time per date in one row for example i have this table:

```
+---------+------------------------+----------+
|name     |Dates                   |Door      |
+---------+------------------------+----------+
|Maria    |2012-02-14 09:04:45.397 |Garage    |
|Maria    |2012-02-14 12:14:20.997 |Entrance |
|Maria    |2013-02-14 12:20:59.407 |Exit      |
|Maria    |2012-02-13 12:24:20.997 |garage    |
|Eli      |2013-02-13 10:30:59.407 |Entrance  |
|Eli      |2013-02-13 12:30:59.407 |Exit      |
+---------+------------------------+----------+
```

the results should be like :

```
+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
|name     |Entrance                |Exit                         |
+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
|Maria    |2012-02-14 09:04:45.397 |2013-02-14 12:20:59.407      |
|Maria    |2012-02-13 12:14:20.997 |          null               |
|Eli      |2013-02-13 10:30:59.407 |2013-02-13 12:30:59.407      |
+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

any help would appreciate :)

Comment: Enctrance or entrance ?

Comment: Entrance / Exit or Min / Max ? Per day or name ?

Comment: So 'entrance' is anything that's not 'edit' ? It's very confusing

Comment: its complex query not simple, im trying to build it 2 days now, i need only the max and min time per day and per name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
    SELECT name, min(dates) as ENTRANCE, IF(max(dates)=MIN(dates),null,max(dates)) as 'Exit' 
from TEST3 GROUP BY name,day(dates);
```

Comment: i assume your dates column is datetime type

Comment: can you try above query it should work if work please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the first part of the result set.

Shouldn't it be as follows??

```
+-------+---------------------+----------+
| name  | date                | door     |
+-------+---------------------+----------+
| Eli   | 2013-02-13 10:30:59 | Entrance |
| Maria | 2012-02-13 12:24:20 | Garage   |
| Maria | 2012-02-14 09:04:45 | Garage   |
+-------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: yes it should be like :  name | date min | date max | door ( the value of the date min record)

Comment: Unfortunately, the lapse of time has caused me to forget what this was all about. I don't think I can be bothered to start over.